# PayPal PayFlow Pro Reporting API returning 110 Invalid merchant account

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, payflowpro, bluedragon

I'm trying to write a script to search the PayPal PayFlow Reporting tool in ColdFusion and I'm stuck in the connection part of this. The response I'm getting back is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<reportingEngineResponse>
    <baseResponse>
        <responseCode>110</responseCode>
        <responseMsg>Invalid merchant account</responseMsg>
    </baseResponse>
</reportingEngineResponse>
```

This is the exact same password combo I'm using to process payments so I know that the vendor,username, password, partner are all correct.  I'm not sure if the XML isn't right, or if I'm sending the XML in incorrectly from BlueDragon (ColdFusion).

This is what my code currently looks like, and I'm trying to pull information from my recurring profile for this account ID.

```
<cfparam name="payPalServerSearch" default="https://payments-reports.paypal.com/reportingengine">

<cfsavecontent variable="req"><cfoutput>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reportingEngineRequest>
    <authRequest>
        <user>#payPalUsername#</user>
        <vendor>#payPalVendor#</vendor>
        <partner>#payPalPartner#</partner>
        <password>#payPalPassword#</password>
    </authRequest>

    <runSearchRequest>
        <searchName>RecurringBillingSearch</searchName>

        <reportParam>
            <paramName>profile_id</paramName>
            <paramValue>I-1234567890</paramValue>
        </reportParam>

        <pageSize>50</pageSize>
    </runSearchRequest>
</reportingEngineRequest>
</cfoutput></cfsavecontent>

<cfset req = trim(req)>

<cfhttp url="#payPalServerSearch#" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#req#">
</cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the profile ID parameter value of I-1234567890 and you are running Live environment based on the URL you are posting "https://payments-reports.paypal.com/reportingengine"

Is this a valid profile ID? I get that the Invalid Merchant account might not be the issue of Profile ID being passed as parameter, but can you try to make sure if it is valid one first and try to run the API call again?

Comment: I-1234567890 is an actual live profile ID, I just used a dummy value of that for this post since all my values are stored in the DB and field in my code was #paypalProfileID#

I'm not sure where or how the merchant ID is still wrong in that.